# Same project but another Android Studio, app not installed

Tags: android, android-studio

I wrote an android app that works fine, but when copy the project and open from another android studio by the exact sdk & same app Id and try to debug; android studio wants to uninstall the last app i install from first Android Studio.
How to prevent uninstalling the existing app and just update that.

Comment: It'd uninstall and re install the newly built app. I do not see any reason you'd want to prevent it

Comment: by "another android studio" you mean a completely different machine?

Comment: @Saurabh yes in my team we have several pc with the same android-Studio version and sdk, and it happen every time we import the project from another pc

Comment: @OBX Because that would lose any data stored by the old app (by default an install via Android Studio does not wipe the data directory.  An uninstall does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because all systems have different debug(auto generated) signing keys. if you don't want to unintsall app installed by another system, you have to make sure both are using same `debug.keystore`. so just copy paste the `debug.keystore` from one system to another and you're good to go.

Its location for mac/Linux is:

`~/.android/debug.keystore`

and windows is

`C:\Users\<Username>\.android\debug.keystore`

Comment: When I'm working on a group product, I tend to just check my debug key into source control, so we can all use it.  Saves problems like this.

Comment: wow, great, but i have another problem, i can't find the debug.keystore. Hidden & system file are visible. im windows user

Comment: @HamidGoodarzi type `%HOMEPATH%\.android` in explorer and look there.

Comment: thanks for such a nice technique, i find the ".android" but there is just this folders{avd, cache, studio} i didn't find debug.keystore. still searching...